# How to show link upload option on statuses updates form which converts to embedded content?

Tags: 7, media

I am using [Statuses (Social Microblog)](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) module to allow users to post status updates like other social networks. To enable users to upload photos and videos, there is a module called [Facebook-style Micropublisher](https://www.drupal.org/project/fbsmp), which allows users to upload links, photos, videos and documents. The problem with this is that all photos and videos will be saved on my server and for a community site, it is an expensive thing.

To counter that, I installed the great [oEmbed](https://www.drupal.org/project/oembed) module. When the oEmbed input filter is turned on in any of the text formats, It allows users to share a url of the video or photo and it embeds it into the statuses update a user shares. The oEmbed filter is working perfectly, but when a user shares a url of a video or photo with text before or after the url, the content is not embedded and it simply shows a link in the status update.

Now there are few ideas I have in my mind, but I do not know whether those ideas are possible or not. I guess it's a challenge.

**Here are the ideas:**

**IDEA 1.** The [Facebook style micro publisher (fbsmp)](https://www.drupal.org/project/fbsmp) module allows to attach a link with the status update. It is designed to work as I want, it is not working as it should. If you install and see this module, i think you will get the idea of how it works.

I have read some where that the statuses module's api is flexible and customizations can be done. I am using the dev version of the statuses and [flag 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag).

**Important note:** It is not necessary that the answer is restricted to my ideas. Anything which solves my problem will do.

Comment: These modules might be of some help [custom filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/customfilter) and [flexi filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexifilter)

Comment: I'm not sure whether it will work for links in content as well, but did you tried [Statuses with Scald integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses_scald) Module as well?

Comment: It seems you have reported this as a bug to the oEmbed module twice already (I just closed one of them). If you genuinely think this is a bug, there is nothing we can for you here, nor is this the place to ask for alternative modules. The way the question is currently written makes it look like you want us to try and validate your ideas. Do not get me wrong, but you are the developer. Don't expect from us to start trying your ideas. Please explain what you have tried with the other modules and what did and did not work.

Comment: @Neograph734 I am not here to ask help for removing bug from oembed. If you read my question, I have told the readers that "What I want to do" and "What I have tried". I did not understand what you mean by "you are a developer". FYI, I do not know how to code.

Comment: See also [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): _your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ... for ..., what do you use?"_

Answer (score 0):

So do you want it to act like Facebook aka pulling in content from the link automadgicly?
If so then I did have some success with a alter / Ajax callback and then file read contents and pulling in an image tag at appropriate size was not the best solution but look in to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476212/save-image-from-url-with-curl-php

And file_get_contents()

Comment: If I put it simply. I want a solution which converts url into an embedded content. Currently, oembed filter is working perfectly. The only problem I am having with it is that when I write text with the url, it does not convert. For example: **Will Convert**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T26oz9H-VBY **Will Not convert**: Nice video must watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T26oz9H-VBY

Answer (score 0):

I went through the module, however I didn't have the time to try out the module. I think there should be a manner to change the way the request is interpreted. Maybe you should try reading parts of the module to see where you can intercept.

- Implement `hook_oembed_request_alter()` to see if you can alter the way the module interprets the request or to see if the module gets a request at all.
- Implement your own `provider` (if need be) and extract / interpret the URL yourself.

I hope it helps. I am interested in the problem. Will see if I can check it out this weekend.

Comment: I would recommend you to try the module and see its docs as well. I am sure it will encourage you. See the above links I  have shared in my comments.